# Add images to a gridview in android periodically

Tags: android, gridview

I need to add images to a gridview in Android, these images are taken from the phone camera like this:

```
Intent camera_intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

After I take the picture with my phone I call the imageAdapter

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(requestCode){
    case 0:
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
           Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
           GridView gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.GridV1);
           gv.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, thumbnail));
         }
    }
}
```

I´m using the Android developers guide to make my grid view, however that only shows how to do it with predetermined images that are on the project folders, and it loads all of them at the same time (Note: Bitmap bMap is my image taken from the phone)

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private Bitmap Bit;

public ImageAdapter(Context c, Bitmap bMap) {

    mContext = c;
    Bit = bMap;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) { 
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(130, 130));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}
```

}

How do I change this code to allow me to add images periodically? I already managed to get 1 image in the gridview, but when I try to add another one it replaces it with the last picture I took.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a new adapter every time you need to modify the data of your adapter, and then call notifydatasetchanged on adapter